# How to remove row if date is older than Today - 15 days

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, delete-row

I want to delete all the rows of a sheet that match my criteria which is:

- Column F contains "YES"
- Date on column A is <= than TODAY - 15

I've tried this code but the formula doesn't work:

```
function deleterows() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var lastrowtraining = ss.getSheetByName("Training").getRange("D:D").getValues().filter(String).length
var training = ss.getSheetByName("Training").getRange(1,1,lastrowtraining+4,42).getValues()  


//Here I define TODAY - 15  
var today = new Date(new Date().setHours(23,59,59,0,0))
var todayminus15 = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate()-15))

// Here I define the columns
for(i=0;j<lastrowtraining+3;i++){
  var rowtraining = i+1;
  var date = training[i][0]
  var city = training[i][1]
  var trainingcomplete = training[i][5]

  if(trainingcomplete =='YES' && date <= todayminus15) {training.deleteRow(rowtraining)}
}
}
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot find function deleteRow in object "Date,City Code,Name,Email,Phone,Successfully completed training,Days since registration if not complete,Send reminder?,Acuity ID,Successfully doc
... (which is the content of the entire sheet)
```

Comment: `getValues()` returns a two-dimensional array containing the values, you cannot call `deleteRow()` on that. Since it's an array though, you can call Array functions on it, like `.filter()`: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/pk86ud23/

Comment: Look like you refer to wrong place.  `var training` is a result of `getRange()`, I suppose you must refer to `ss.deleteRow()`

Comment: @lazy.lizard I don't think so, I need to specify the sheet somehow

Comment: @ChrisG how can I delete it then?

Comment: If you want to change the sheet, you need to call `deleteRow()` on the sheet itself.

Comment: @MàriusMontmany `ss` is an instance of spreadsheet object that contains all it's methods. I suppose it's `ss.deleteRow(rowtraining)`

Comment: and yes, @ADW seems to give correct answer below

Comment: @lazy.lizard Thanks for the quick reply. 
I've added this and modified the rows and it works...
... **BUT** only deletes the first row that matches the criteria

Do you know why it could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @ADW, @Chris G and @lazy.lizard.

Main problem was that I was triggering action `deleteRow` on training which was a `getValues` an `deleteRow` needs a sheet.

So this half solved the problem:

```
var training = trainingsheet.getRange(1,1,lastrowtraining+4,42).getValues(); // change this line
```

But, (I already don't know why) this code only works on the first row that matches the criteria so I add a trigger to the `deleterowsnew()`function after the row was deleted:

```
if(trainingcomplete =='YES' && date <= todayminus15) {trainingsheet.deleteRow(rowtraining);deleterowsnew()}
```

So the final code ends up like this:

```
function deleterowsnew() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lastrowtraining = ss.getSheetByName("Training").getRange("D:D").getValues().filter(String).length
  var trainingsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Training")
  var training = trainingsheet.getRange(1,1,lastrowtraining+4,42).getValues()  


  //Here I define TODAY - 15  
  var today = new Date(new Date().setHours(23,59,59,0,0))
  var todayminus15 = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate()-15))

  // Here I define the columns:
  for(i=0;i<lastrowtraining+3;i++){
    var rowtraining = i+1;
    var date = training[i][0]
    var city = training[i][1]
    var trainingcomplete = training[i][5]

    //I define here the condition and after it's completed and trigger the action again to be completed if another row matches the criteria
    if(trainingcomplete =='YES' && date <= todayminus15) {trainingsheet.deleteRow(rowtraining);deleterowsnew()}

  }
}
```

Thank you all for the help and hope this can help you on the future!

Comment: You should convert both `todayminus15` and `date` to timestamp, use `Date.parse()` for them. Keep in mind milliseconds - they may not present in `date`.

Answer (score 2):

The `deleteRow` method works on a sheet. Not on the data value array from the sheet.

Try:

```
var trainingSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Training"); // insert this line
var training = trainingSheet.getRange(1,1,lastrowtraining+4,42).getValues(); // change this line
```

And then use: `trainingSheet.deleteRow(rowtraining)`

Instead of: `training.deleteRow(rowtraining)`

---

**Edit**

When deleting rows it is best to go upwards from the bottom. Going downwards causes this problem: say you had to delete rows 5 and 6.

After you delete row 5, all the lower rows have moved up. So when you delete row 6, this is actually the original row 7 that has moved up.

So best to run the loop in reverse like so:

```
for (var i = lastrowtraining + 2; i >= 0; i--){
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. @ADW

I've added this and modified the rows and it works...
... **BUT** only deletes the first row that matches the criteria

Do you know why it could be?

Comment: Did `deleterowsnew()` solve the problem? I realised there could be another issue. So edited my response above.